# Pipreqs only list one local package and not same version than in requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I struggle understanding the [`pipreqs`](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) behaviour.

In my project, I use a virtualenv (Pipreqs is installed globally). I have a `requirements.txt` file that I first wrote manually, then I did a `pip freeze` and now I have way more packages than I want (because there are dependencies of dependencies...).

So I found pipreqs to get a requirements file with only the packages that matter.

I activate my virtualenv then `pipreqs --savepath requirements2.txt --use-local`.

I use `--use-local` cause I want the currently installed versions of my packages.

And I end up with a file with only one package (not even the version used in my project)...

Without `--use-local` it seems to retrieve the correct number of packages but the versions are the "up-to-date" ones, not the ones in my project.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for the help